# MVC Radio buttons checked state not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a view where I am trying to assign whether a radio button is checked. I have 2 elements, **Grouped** and **Variant**. I assigned the **grouped** to be `checked`, but the **variant** (second one) is always `checked`. IF I add more elements, it is always the last one that is `checked`.

```
<div>
 @Html.Label("Grouped")
 @Html.RadioButton("familyType", "grouped", new { @checked = true})             
 @Html.Label("Variant")
 @Html.RadioButton("familyType", "variant", new { @checked = false})       
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "checked" property does not have a boolean value. The only acceptable value is "checked".

```
checked="checked"
```

Just by having the "checked" attribute the radio/checkbox will make it checked.

If you do not want the radio/checkbox to be checked, then do not include the "checked" attribute.